# Why does the string string in the post request contain "{\">\"" that cannot be requested

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, post

I have a string in the post request, which contains the information

```
{
"itemCondition": "{\"and\":[{\"==\":[{\"var\":\"powerSwitch\"},\"1\"]},{\">\":[{\"var\":\"guardSensitivity\"},\"0\"]}]}"
}
```

But the greater than comparison symbol in the middle cannot be escaped

The error message is as follows

```
[org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('\' (code 92)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('\' (code 92)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
| at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]]  [WARN END]
```

I don't understand why > is replaced by == again. I have tried >, <, <=, >=, but I can't realize the request, only == succeeded

Comment: It's unclear what you're actually posting or what exactly is being parsed. From the error it *looks* like the string `"{\"and\" etc."` is being parsed, and if there's actually a `\` in there, it's true, that wouldn't be valid JSON.

Comment: No, ** "{\"and\" ** here can be parsed, and {\"==\"here can also be parsed, that is, the {\">\ "of the comparative symbol can not be parsed to the following\

Comment: https://theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/backslash-reverse-slash-ascii-code-92.html